# jQuery .on('click') firing multiple times when used with :not() selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good morning,

I have a set of boxes on a page that are presented as a list, and within these boxes there might be some links that can be clicked. I want the links within the boxes to work as normal (i.e. bubble up and either perform the default action or then be handled by event handlers further up the DOM), but if the box is clicked anywhere else then it should be caught by a particular event handler attached to the "list" containing all the boxes.

Simple html representation

```
<div class="boxlist">
    <div class="box" data-boxid="1">
        Some text, and possibly a <a href="#">link</a> and another <a href="#">link</a>, and perhaps even a third <a href="#">link</a>.
    </div>
    <div class="box" data-boxid="2">
        Some more text, this time without a link.
    </div>
</div>
```

The javascript that I thought should work.

```
$(function () {
    $('.boxlist').on('click', '.box :not(a)', function (e) {
        var boxid= $(this).closest('.box').data('boxid');
        console.log('open: ' + boxid);
    });
});
```

My expectation was that the above javascript should handle all clicks that did not originate from  tags. However, for some reason when the box is clicked (either the box itself, or an  tag, doesn't matter), it fires this event X times, where X is the total number of  tags within the list of boxes.

So I have two questions:
1. What am I doing wrong with the :not() selector.
2. Is there a better way to handle this scenario?

Thank you for helping!

Comment: With the code you show, as the only descendant of '.box' are the 'a' elements, the event handler will never be called. But even if you add other children, assuming they're not nested, there doesn't seem to be a reason for what you say to see. Can you build a fiddle (http://jsbin.com for example) ?

Comment: remove the space `'.box :not(a)'` between `.box` and `:not(a)`

Comment: @Jai This doesn't seem to be the goal.

Comment: @dystroy Ah got it now agreed with you.

Comment: @dystroy removing the space does actually reduce the number of calls to one, however the event handler is still called even when an a tag is clicked. Give me a moment and will try to make a jsbin for this.

Comment: have a look at [Event Target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/). Identify which tag is clicked. `box` or `a` itself and perform action. That way you won't be needing `:not` selector.

Comment: @dystroy made the jsbin, and also added some more structure to it (actual scenario is not such simple boxes). In the jsbin example however it doesn't fire multiple times. But neither does it fire when the box itself is clicked.

Comment: @MiikaL. I explained why it doesn't fire when the box is clicked : your selector look for descendant elements and the only one are the `a` elements. Your real problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

linkUsing jQuery :not selector actually is very slow ex:http://jsperf.com/not-vs-notdasdsad/4 and it's way better to just use [event delegation](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate). So in this case you want to keep track of every click on the .boxlist but check the node type to see if its an anchor or not. This is an example.

```
$(function () {
    $('.boxlist').on('click', function(ev){
        if(ev.target.tagName != "A"){
            // handle box click code
            console.log('box click');
            return false;
        }
        // Otherwise allow event to bubble through.
    });
});
```

and here is a jsfiddle example
http://jsfiddle.net/drXmA/

Also their are a few reasons your code doesn't work

```
.box :not(a)
```

should be

```
.box:not(a)
```

and the reason this also does not work is because .box is not an anchor tag it has children elements that are anchor tags it will never find an anchor tag named .box if their is one the callback would not execute. Changing the .box to an anchor tag will make it so the code doesn't execute because .box is an anchor and it is only running when .box:not(a)

Comment: This doesn't explain OP's problem with handler fired multiple times.

Comment: I couldn't even get his example to work to see it fired multiple times. What he posted didn't do anything in jsfiddle for me.

Comment: Yes, for me neither (see comments under the question), that's why I didn't post an alternative. I don't say your answer is bad, it may be a solution to OP's problem, I just say it's at best half an answer.

Comment: @dystroy I can't seem to reproduce the multiple event issue in jsbin either. The actual content of the box is a complex structure, not simple text, which is loaded in via ajax (hence the click event attached to the list which exists at the time of binding. However, this answer might actually give me the solution I need to move forward.

Comment: So accept it. You probably had either a problem with nested .box or you executed the binding instruction more than once.

Comment: I suggested a small edit to your answer so that it fits my criteria exactly, and will now accept it as this answers the core problem. The multiple events will remain a mystery unless I can somehow reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want something like this:

```
$('.boxlist').on('click', '.box:not(a)', function (e) {
   var boxid = $(this).closest('.box').data('boxid');
   console.log('open: ' + boxid);
}).on('click', '.box a', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault().stopPropagation();
});
```

#### [DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6peyQ/)

I think better to stop the default behavior and stop the event bubbling to its parent. `.on()` chain to the `.box` items excluding `<a>` from it and stop the default behavior and event bubble with `e.preventDefault().stopPropagation();`

Comment: No, I specifically do not want the stop propagations on the a tags, because I want them to bubble past the box and be handled elsewhere.